# Информация про типы и варианты кнопок для android с примерами

Tags: android, android-button

Интересуют ресурсы, где много примеров. Спасибо.
Отличный пример: [Components - Buttons](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html)

Comment: Вопрос немного оффтопик, но вот вам пара ссылок: [Buttons](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) и [Components– Buttons](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html)

Comment: А вообще не очень понятно что именно вам надо и чем вам поисковики не помогли... Сомневаюсь что-то где-то есть прямо совсем про все кнопки статья... Тем паче на великом и могучем.

Answer (score 1):

В официальной документации, вероятно.
Можно и [вот тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php).
А вот [ссылка](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) на официальную.